# Flutter - Refresh home page on item tap in drawer

Tags: flutter, navigation, state, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to refresh home page when an item in drawer is tapped.

HomeView is a stateful widget which returns a Scaffold with a drawer like this:

```
 Scaffold(
        drawer: const ProfileDrawer(), ....
```

I made a function which just calls setState in home like this:

```
  void refreshPage() {
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Drawer has a listview which returns GestureDetector widgets as below:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    profileNotifier(false).setActiveProfile = index;
    HomeView().refreshPage();
    Navigator.pop(context);
  },
  child: ....
);
```

But on drawer class I'm getting error `The method 'refreshPage' isn't defined for the type 'HomeView'`. So I searched about it and learnt that method inside state cannot be called from elsewhere. But then when I moved the refreshPage function to class definition so that it can be called, now I can't setState.

I just want home to be refreshed when I tap on the drawer item. Any way to do this will work for a very grateful me.

Answer (score 0):

Have been using this trick since then.
In your case, the page `HomeView` should be `statefulWidget`:

> Hope you can adapt this code to your needs.

- creating a GlobalKey for you HomeView like bellow

  ```
  class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
    //remove the const and add customKey
    HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: GlobalKey<_HomeViewState>());

    @override
    State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();

    //this is used to call the refreshPage method of your State
    void refreshPage() {
      print("call the state-method");
      (key as GlobalKey<_HomeViewState>).currentState?.refreshPage();
    }
  }
  class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
    void refreshPage() {
      setState(() {
        print("method called");
      });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container();
    }
  }
  ```
- create an instance of HomeView outside the GestureDetector

eg:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//you can create the instance here (it depends on your use cases)
HomeView homeView = HomeView();

class A extends StatefulWidget{
  ...
}
class _AState extends State<A>{
  ...
  return Scaffold(
    drawer: ProfileDrawer(homeViewRef:homeView), //your drawer must have reference of your homeView instance
  );
}
```

Drawer eg:

```
class ProfileDrawer{
  ...
  final HomeView homeViewRef;
  ProfileDrawer({required this.homeViewRef}){
  ...
  }

  //where this must be
  GestureDetector(){
    ...
    homeViewRef.refreshPage();
    ...
  }
}
```

- you should change this line: `HomeView().refreshPage();` with `homeViewRef.refreshPage();` because you are trying to call refreshPage() of new instance of HomeView (so then avoid).

Comment: I couldn't understand the second method you suggested, whether I need to create another file with a new class, so I used the first one. The function in stateful widget is called, but it doesn't in turn call the function in its state. I thought it's got to do with `currentState?` so I changed it to `currentState!` and it seems it is null. What to do now?